# Scrape nested html with python, search box results

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am trying to understand how to get a list of URLs to scrape from a search box in Cyrillic website.
This is the results page, and the search term is "коронавирус" (it's 'windows-1251'):
https://www.dnes.bg/search.php?q=%EA%EE%F0%EE%ED%E0%E2%E8%F0%F3%F1

I am trying to get the URLs only under a tag like this one:

```
<div class="ttl mb0"><a href="/notifikacii/2020/03/24/greta-tunberg-veroiatno-bila-bolna-ot-covid-19.443414">Грета Тунберг "вероятно" била болна от COVID-19</a></div>
```

but it's a nested structure.
The xpath is:

```
//*[@id="c1"]/div[4]/div[1]/a
```

With BeautifulSoup's find_all('a') I find all the links, and I don't need everything, just the search results.

A full-code answer would be most helpful!

Answer (score 1):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get(
    "https://www.dnes.bg/search.php?q=%EA%EE%F0%EE%ED%E0%E2%E8%F0%F3%F1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')


urls = [f"{r.url[:19]}{item.get('href')}" for item in soup.select(
    "div.ttl.mb0 a")]

print(urls)
```

Output:

```
['https://www.dnes.bg/notifikacii/2020/03/24/greta-tunberg-veroiatno-bila-bolna-ot-covid-19.443414', 'https://www.dnes.bg/koronavirusat/2020/03/24/kitai-otpuska-merkite-a-evropa-i-sasht-zatiagat-rejima.443411', 'https://www.dnes.bg/mish-mash/2020/03/24/etiket-po-vreme-na-koronavirus-ne-pliuite-i-spazvaite-distanciia.443348', 'https://www.dnes.bg/eu/2020/03/24/jivotyt-v-shveciia-na-pylni-oboroti-koronavirus-li.443384', 'https://www.dnes.bg/akoshtete-vqrvaite/2020/03/24/pri-izolaciia-5-syveta-protiv-preiajdane.443357', 'https://www.dnes.bg/akoshtete-vqrvaite/2020/03/24/po-vreme-na-pandemiia-zashto-panicheski-se-prezapasiavame.443402', 'https://www.dnes.bg/obshtestvo/2020/03/24/v-kriza-podkrepiame-merkite-i-vlastta-strah-ni-e-ot-bezrabotica.443342', 'https://www.dnes.bg/notifikacii/2020/03/24/bolnite-v-italiia-namaliavat-no-bolnicite-vse-oshte-sa-pretovareni.443409', 'https://www.dnes.bg/obshtestvo/2020/03/24/bolnite-ot-koronavirus-u-nas-veche-sa-218.443395', 'https://www.dnes.bg/cars/2020/03/24/avtomobilnite-kompanii-shte-zapochnat-da-proizvejdat-ventilatori.443330', 'https://www.dnes.bg/stranata/2020/03/24/deteto-s-pnevmoniia-v-tyrnovskata-bolnica-bez-vaksini.443405', 'https://www.dnes.bg/koronavirusat/2020/03/24/razrabotiha-inhalator-za-cialostno-lechenie-sreshtu-koronavirus.443295', 'https://www.dnes.bg/koronavirusat/2020/03/24/kiril-domuschiev-prebori-koronavirusa-veche-e-dobre.443401', 'https://www.dnes.bg/koronavirusat/2020/03/24/matematicheski-model-shte-pokazva-licata-pod-karantina-v-burgas.443389', 'https://www.dnes.bg/koronavirusat/2020/03/24/osma-jertva-vze-koronavirusyt-v-rumyniia.443331', 'https://www.dnes.bg/balkani/2020/03/24/syrbiia-nastypva-sreshtu-covid-19-s-masovi-testove.443376', 'https://www.dnes.bg/koronavirusat/2020/03/24/blizo-do-kitai-a-samo-1128-zarazeni-s-koronavirus-kak-go-postigna-iaponiia.443374', 'https://www.dnes.bg/sport/2020/03/24/oficialno-olimpiiskite-igri-shte-se-provedat-prez-2021-g.443380', 'https://www.dnes.bg/sport/2020/03/24/bez-tenis-i-sport-kak-se-podgotvia-viktoriia-tomova-vkyshti.443321', 'https://www.dnes.bg/koronavirusat/2020/03/24/vinovnikyt-za-pandemiiata-ot-covid-19-globalizaciiata.443316']
```

> Please check [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Thx, it works, but I still can't figure code elements like f", :19 and other non-explicit ones. Say , I want to get a different tag in nested structure, what should I follow?
E.g., I'd want to extract the titles from the <a href=... >

Comment: hi there - good day dear αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη - i am Zero the learner here on this site. Many thanks for the solution i can see that this works for me too. BTW - testing my setup with workin examples  - and your solutions  work - and are great learing assets - keep up the great work - it rocks  ;)

Comment: @Julian you are asking a questions which is completely leads that you don't know the basics of the language which you are using, such as `Format-String` and `Slice-String`, a question of what you are asking is completely got answered for thousands time if you made some search on the `community`, that's will not be more efficient if we keep answer duplicated questions daily !

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη apparently, I'm not specialized in this, and I couldn't find anything online directly working for my case. Yet, I'm sure it's a simple job for someone familiar with the matter.
On your comment: I don't find here or in the link explanation to why this code works, so this doesn't help to understanding how to get nested tags and isolate them from the rest. 
And after all, no one makes you reply, but yet, the more "duplicated" questions there are, the easier it will be for them to be found by anyone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, req, utils
url = 'https://www.dnes.bg/search.php?q=%EA%EE%F0%EE%ED%E0%E2%E8%F0%F3%F1'
html = '''
<div class="ttl mb0"><a href="/notifikacii/2020/03/24/greta-tunberg-veroiatno-bila-bolna-ot-covid-19.443414">Грета
    Тунберг "вероятно" била болна от COVID-19</a></div>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
urls = doc.selects('div.ttl mb0').a
urls = [(utils.absoluteUrl(url,u.href),u.text) for u in urls]
print (urls)
```

Result:

```
[('https://www.dnes.bg/notifikacii/2020/03/24/greta-tunberg-veroiatno-bila-bolna-ot-covid-19.443414', 'Грета Тунберг "вероятно" била болна от COVID-19')]
```